# Querying MySQL with IN clause using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to do a query similar to the following:

```
SELECT f_name, l_name, title from
-> employee_data where title 
-> IN ('Web Designer', 'System Administrator');
```

The search terms are received in an array `$data = ['Web Designer', 'System Administrator']` and right now I can turn that array into `Web Designer,System Administrator` using:

```
 $data = implode(',', $data)
```

Is there a good way to turn that array into `'Web Designer', 'System Administrator'` so I can insert this phrase into the MySQL query directly as shown at the beginning of the post?

Comment: I assume you also want to protect yourself against SQL injection, but just forgot to mention it, right?

Comment: How do I protect myself against SQL injection? Sorry I'm new to this

Comment: @Nyxynyx: Read up on using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [prepared queries](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) in particular.

Comment: @Nyxynyx see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably should use:

```
$data = implode( ', ', array_map( $data, array( $object, 'escape')));
$query .= 'title IN ( ' . $data . ')'; // Append to condition
```

Where `$object->escape()` would by function like:

```
public function $escape( $string){
   return "'" . mysql_real_escape_string( $string, $this->connection) . "'";
}
```

Here's [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) documentation, and [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php). This should be [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) proof solution.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 $data = array('Web Designer', 'System Administrator');
 $query_include = "'".implode("','",$data)."'";
 $query ="SELECT f_name, l_name, title from
          employee_data where title 
           IN ($query_include);";
```

as Vyktor pointed out that SQL injection can happen and I fully agree so without changing the above code I will sort of prepend this code to above

```
 function clean(&$item) {
  $item = mysql_real_escape_string($item);
 }
array_walk($data,"clean");
```

Comment: How sql injection was born, do something about it :)

Comment: oh yes thats right forgot to handle that. Thanks Vyktor. Editing my answer now. I've an article here which deals with this problem. pretty much in line http://jaspreetchahal.org/php-add-wrap-single-quote-around-all-array-values-separated-by-comma-in-php/

Comment: Yeah, that's better... It's very similar to my approach .)

Comment: yes thats right but your is based on OOP and mine structural :) we both deserve another +! I guess hehe. Do you mind If I add your solution to my blog post??

Comment: here you go :D +1 but use `mysql_real_escape_string()` [http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php ], `mysql_escape_string()` is deprecated [http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php ]

Comment: I +1d u too. I know whats the difference :) just felt lazy i guess hehe

Comment: Actually that's why I choose OOP not procedural approach to be able to call `mysql_real_escape_string()` in correct way

Comment: `DEPRECATED` = will be removed in future versions.

Comment: I know man but Very special thanks for sharing. others will benefit from it. I've changed that on all my projects too to be on safe side.

Comment: I'm taking these input values via `getJSON` from browser to PHP backend using Codeigniter `$this->input->get('var_name')`. Does Codeigniter cleans them automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can

```
$data = "'"
        .implode("','", $data).
        "'";
```

it is a bit unreadable, but it's working.
Also make sure that `$data` is not user data or if so, make sure it's sanitized.

Answer (score 0):

modify the query like this:

```
$query = 'SELECT f_name, l_name, title from
         -> employee_data where title 
         -> IN (\'' . implode('\', \'', $data) . '\')';
```