# MySQL Query not working with PHP Variable?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

Why is this working:

```
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM Content WHERE id IN (1,5,7,9)";
```

But this isn't:

```
$array_values = "1,5,7,9";
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM Content WHERE id IN ('$array_values')";
```

I want to select data from the database based on the integers in the $array_values string.
How can I do it?

Comment: `IN (1,5,7,9)` is four integer values, however `IN ('1,5,7,9')` is one string value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Querying MySQL with IN clause using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236460/querying-mysql-with-in-clause-using-php)

Comment: As Scuzzy said, use: `IN ($array_values)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because there are `` ` `` s in your code here

```
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM Content WHERE id IN ('$array_values')";
```

use :

```
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM Content WHERE id IN ( $array_values )";
```

or

```
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM Content WHERE id IN (".$array_values.")";
```

Comment: Allows SQL injection attacks if the values are user input

Comment: Thanks that helped me!

Comment: @NineBerry in my case it's not an user Input